# What term can we use to describe two quantities whose sum is a constant? (e.g. inversely proportional if their product is a constant?)

Tags: linear-algebra

When the product of 2 quantities is a constant we call them inversely proportional. What term can we use to describe two quantities whose sum is a constant? I used 'inversely proportional" multiple times to describe this situation on an assignment draft and was told by my lecturer that it was an incorrect usage of the term (he didn't offer any suggestions though).

Comment: As far as I know, there is no name for such a situation ; you find sometimes, when the sum is 1, the expression: $b$ is  "complementary to 1 with respect to" $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think *complementary* (as suggested by JeanMarie) is the right word.

For example, complementary angles add up to 90 degrees.

As another example, the complement of set $A$ is everything in some universal set that is not in $A$, so that the set and its complement add up to (i.e. have union equal to) the universal set. (Which is why if event $A$ has probability $p$ then we say $1-p$ is the "complementary probability".)

Comment: Do complementary terms have to "add up to 90 degrees" or "1"? Thanks

Comment: As long as you make it explicit what you mean (e.g. by providing a definition) it does not matter. For example if you have two quantities $a$ and $b$ that add to $T$, then you can simply say the complement of $a$ is $b=T-a$. But is there really any need to use a special word?

Comment: It would be nice, as the assignment I'm doing has a word limit so using a 'special word' will save me a couple of words each time I need to use the term. Also, thanks.